# Google cloud 404 after verifying file exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have another project where this same code works successfully, so it may be some configuration option I've missed this time around. I'm using the google cloud API to access firebase storage.

For clarity, the file **does** exist.

```js
var storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')({
  keyFilename: 'serviceAccountKey.json',
  projectId: 'my-id'
 });
var bucket = storage.bucket('my-id.appspot.com');

var file = bucket.file('directory/file.json'); //this exists!
file.exists(function(err, exists){
   console.log("Checking for challenges file. Results:" + exists + ", err:" + err); //returns "Checking for challenges file. Results:true, err:nil"
       if (exists) {
     console.log("File exists. Printing."); //prints "File exists. Printing."
     file.download().then(function(currentFileData) {
      console.log("This line is never reached.");
     }).catch(err => {
      console.error('ERROR:', err); //gives a 404 error
     });
       }
});
```

Instead of printing "this line is never reached.", it prints the following caught error:
`ERROR: { ApiError: Not Found at Object.parseHttpRespMessage (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:156:33) at Object.handleResp ... ...` The full error is colossal, so I won't post it here in its entirety unless required.

Comment: Buckets are tied to projects. Are you sure in both of your projects you have the same file in the same directory?

Comment: Yes, I'm certain. I have X number of files (max 8), and I re-run this code with a changing file variable. When I have 3 files, it runs 3 times (because Exists is found true 3 times), but then errors 3 times (because I generate 3 404 errors, one for each existing file).

Comment: Checking the documentation for Google Cloud, nothing looks bad with your code, so I can only think of it being a problem of permissions in the bucket, maybe you can list files but you don't have access to the file contents?

Comment: Could you include the full code including how you authenticate and set up the bucket object?

Comment: I don't know how much I can include without invoking the ire of my bosses, but hopefully what I added helps. I think @MondKin is right, though. If the code works identically between the two projects, with only the ID and service key being swapped out, it's definitely permissions. Just not sure which.

Comment: Note that you can receive a 404 when an object actually does exist if the caller doesn't have permission to list the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the user that is trying to access the file only have access over the bucket but not over the file. Check the ACLs of both the bucket and the file in both projects and compare what you get:

```
myBucket.acl.get()
    .then(acls => console.log("Bucket ACLs:", acls));
myFile.acl.get()
    .then(acls => console.log("File ACLs:", acls));
```

You should see an output like this:

```
[ [ { entity: 'user-abenavides333@gmail.com', role: 'OWNER' },
    { entity: 'user-dwilches@gmail.com', role: 'OWNER' } ],
  { kind: 'storage#objectAccessControls',
    items: [ [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```

If there is no difference there, try the following more verbose versions of the same code:

```
myBucket.acl.get()
    .then(acls => console.log("Bucket ACLs:", JSON.stringify(acls, null, '\t')));
myFile.acl.get()
    .then(acls => console.log("File ACLs:", JSON.stringify(acls, null, '\t')));
```